# Is it possible to transfer my old Clash account to my new phone?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've been playing Clash of Clans for over a year and don't want to lose my progress. I know I can transfer it, but the thing is, my iPod doesn't work anymore. So would it be possible to do it without the old device? They are both Apple products by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, go to Settings of clash of clans in game and and click "Help and Support" then Lost village. Give the information they want to know about your previous account.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using game center it should auto sync. Otherwise you're out of luck, because its stored on a server.

Answer (score 0):

when i downloaded the clash of clans app to my new phone i could either open a new account or sign into my old account. so i kept my old village with with all its progress.
(i'm on android though)